# Where can I find the build for ActiveMQ Real Time?

Tags: activemq-classic

There is a mention of ActiveMQ real time on the apache ActiveMQ site. But, I am unable to locate any builds for download.

Is it in alpha stage? Is there any way I can try it out?

I did see the activeblaze in the apache SVN repo. Is it expected that we check out the code, build and try?

http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-real-time.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/what-s-the-status-of-activemq-real-time-td4678344.html) on the ActiveMQ user mailing list the project is "mothballed" (i.e. no longer maintained). That thread was back in 2014.

I joined the ActiveMQ project a few years ago, and I've never seen any development on or questions about any "real time" broker variant.